# calabash testing setup, ANDROID_HOME path

Tags: android, testing

Im trying to use calabash and android for testing. So it is just a started and installed calabash. The problem comes when I try to execute the first test when I run:

```
calabash-android run myAPP.apk
```

I get a response:

```
`raise_if_android_home_not_set': Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable (RuntimeError)
```

How do I setup ANDROID_HOME?
Where do I setup ANDROID_HOME?
From your experience, do you recommend calabash?
Thanks

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Hello, did you manage to sort this out? Would you mind posting the solution? I'm using windows 7 and `set ANDROID_HOME="C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk"` but when I try running the command I get now `No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test server.
D:/workspace/calabash/android/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.3.8/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:9:in calabash_build': No Android SDK found in "C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk"/p
latforms/ (RuntimeError)`. Any clue how I could overcome this?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, about window 7 probably on environment variables, on properties on my computer. Any way Im giving up on calabash I'll go with robotium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the calabash-android run command:
From the terminal just run: export ANDROID_HOME=/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64/sdk

Were you replace the path with the path of your sdk

Answer (score 0):

Edit your ~/.profile file and add in the line:
export ANDROID_HOME=PATH_TO_WHERE_SDK_INSTALLED

Where PATH_TO_WHERE_SDK_INSTALLED is replaced by the actual path to android sdk.

Answer (score 0):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin
```

Restart the shell for the changes to take effect or source it, i.e.:

```
source .bashrc
```

See my blog for more information on getting Calabash set up: whitneytaylorimura.wordpress.com